# Ball doesn't move; Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface

This is an UI that makes a ball go down in a diagonal way, but the ball stays static; it seems something is not working adecuatedly with the threads. Could you please, tell me how to make the ball move?

Please download a ball and change the directory so the program can find where your ball is allocated. It's not necessary to download the soccer pitch but if you want, it's OK. Finally, I have to thank you for spending time in search of this malfunctioning.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;

class Animation extends JFrame implements ActionListener {  //Frame and listener

  Rectangle2D dimensions = new Rectangle2D.Double(0,0,850,595);  //Not implemented limits
  JButton animate, stop;
  Runnable runnable;
  Thread move;

    public Animation() {
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());  //BorderLayout disposition
      setTitle("Pelota en acción");      

        animate = new JButton("Animate it!");  //Button to create balls
          animate.setBounds(0,0,120,30);
          animate.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Image ball = null;
                new Layout().createEllipse(ball);
                runnable = new Layout();
                move = new Thread(runnable);
                  move.start();
               }
          });

          stop = new JButton("Freeze");  //Button to interrupt thread (not implemented)
          stop.setBounds(0,0,120,30);
          stop.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  move.interrupt();
                  Layout.running = false;
              }
          });

        JPanel subPanel = new JPanel();  //Layout with its buttons situated to the south
          subPanel.add(animate);
          subPanel.add(stop);
        add(subPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        add(new Layout());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animation ventana = new Animation();
          ventana.setSize(850,625);
          ventana.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          ventana.setVisible(true);
          ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

  @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {} //Tag
}  //Class close


class Layout extends JPanel implements Runnable {  //Layout and thread

  int X,Y;  //Coordenadas
  static boolean running = true;  //"To interrupt the thread" momentaneously.
  static ArrayList<Image> balls = new ArrayList<>();  //Balls collection

  @Override
    public void run () {  //Just moves ball towards Narnia xd
        while(running) {
          X++; Y++;
            System.out.println(X+" "+Y);
            repaint();
            updateUI();
            try {
              Thread.sleep(4);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }

  @Override
     public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.addRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON));
          repaint();
          updateUI();

        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://www.freejpg.com.ar/image-900/9c/9ca2/F100004898-textura_pasto_verde_linea_de_cal.jpg");
            Image picture = ImageIO.read(url);
              g.drawImage(picture,0,0,null);
        } catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("URL image was not found");
        }
        finally {
          try {     
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
              Image picture = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Home\\Desktop\\Cancha.jpg")); //Pitch
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
                g.drawImage(picture, 0, 0, null);
          } catch (IOException ex) {
              System.out.println("Pitch image was not found");
          }
        }

        for (Image ball : balls) {  //I add balls to the Layout
          g2.drawImage(ball,X,Y,100,100,null);
        }
    }

    public void createEllipse (Image ball) {  //Method that adds balls to the collection
        try {
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------   Ball
            ball = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Home\\Desktop\\Pelota.png"));  //Change this
       //--------------------------------------------------------------------   Ball
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Any balls were found");
        }
        balls.add(ball);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, the first thing I can see is that you call repaint() from an other Thread. This can lead to problems. I'll take a closer look and test your code to see what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks, also I don't know where to put it; ¿Could you tell me please, the place where I need to write it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to break your code down:

When the button is pressed, you execute the following code:

```
Image ball = null;
new Layout().createEllipse(ball);
runnable = new Layout();
move = new Thread(runnable);
move.start();
```

This will create a new layout. The `run()` method of this will increase the `X` and `Y` variables. They are declared here:

```
int X,Y;  //Coordenadas
```

Those are instance variables, this means they belong to your newly created `Layout`.

Then you call `repaint()` on the new `Layout`, which will do nothing, because this new Layout has not been added to some window.

So, how do you fix this?

First, you have to keep the original `Layout` around:

```
class Animation extends JFrame { // no need to implement ActionListener
     Rectangle2D dimensions = new Rectangle2D.Double(0,0,850,595);  //Not implemented limits
     JButton animate, stop;
     Thread move;
     Layout layout;
```

Then remember the Layout when you create it:

```
// before: add(new Layout());
layout = new Layout();
add(layout);
```

Then use the layout in your `ActionListener`:

```
layout.createEllipse(ball);
move = new Thread(layout);
move.start();
```

This might have some problems with concurrency (Swing is not thread-safe), so for good measure, you should call `repaint()` in the AWTEventThread:

```
// in run(), was repaint():
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
       repaint();
   }
});
```

Now, there are some cleanup tasks left:
Delete this code:

```
  @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {} //Tag
```

It's no longer needed, because you don't implement `ActionListener`.

Drop the `static` modifiers from some fields, and add `volatile`:

```
volatile int X,Y;  //Coordenadas
volatile boolean running = true;  //"To interrupt the thread" momentaneously.
ArrayList<Image> balls = new ArrayList<>();  //Balls collection
```

`volatile` is needed for variables that are accessed from more than one thread.

Also remove `repaint()` and `resetUI()` from the `paint` method. You don't need them.

For the pictures in `paint`: you should cache them. Store them in a field, so you don't have to load the picture every time.

When all this is done, your code is much cleaner, but there are still some warts that should be addressed. But at least you have something working.

Comment: `repaint` is thread safe, but modifying the state that the UI relies on from outside the EDT is probably a bad idea, as a repaint could occur at any time and may not be trigged by the code - a simpler solution would be to use a Swing `Timer`

Comment: I agree. Also lambdas would make the code easier to read. There are a lot of things that can be done. Any source for the thread safety on `repaint`?

Comment: Yeah, read the source code .  Seriously, repaint posts a "paint" event request onto the Event Dispatching Thread (via the `RepaintManager`) - it's one of the few methods I know that is thread safe

Comment: Didn't know that. And I will edit the answer if this is mentioned in the spec (javadoc), otherwise it might just be an implementation detail added to not break old code that rely on it. And for thread safety, I better do it from the event thread, that's where I know it's thread safe .

Comment: Seriously, when I need to update the UI from out the EDT, regardless of what I do, I use `invokeLater`, because even the methods mentioned as thread safe, aren't always 

Comment: A friend once had a nice bug. Some library was posting events to the EDT, and in the handler he displayed a JOptionPane. Through some bug, the library posted more than one event, so the next event did open an other JOptionPane. And the application was single threaded. I broke this library by unregistering my event handler inside this event handler. Good times.

Comment: Thanks for answering and the most important thing is that I learnt new concepts. Thanks! Ps: Could you upvote my code?

Comment: Sorry for asking you again, but I don´t completely dominate the Java language. Nevertheless, I had got another problem and it's that the button animate it doesn´t create a new ball; instead of taht, it returns the same ball to the start point and speed it up. Could you explain me please, why it's not creating a new one and why the ball's speed is incrementing? Updated code: https://code.sololearn.com/cEd16IG11o9J/#java

Comment: You should ask a new question for that.

Comment: So, ¿Could you tell me that warts that should be adressed which are mentioned int the last paragraph? Briefly, then you don't take too much time.

Answer (score 2):

Johannes has already spoken about many of the things which are wrong with your original example, so I won't go over many of them again.

This example makes use of a Swing `Timer` instead of a `Thread` as the main "animation" loop.  It also focuses on demonstrating encapsulation and responsibility.

For example, the `AnimtionPane` is responsible for managing the balls, managing the animation loop and paint.  It isn't, however, responsible for determining "how" the balls are updated or paint, it only provides the timing and functionality to make those things happen.

A couple of the glaring issues I can see are:

- Trying to load resources from within the `paintComponent` method.  This is a bad ideas, as it could slow you paint pass down, causing your UI to lag
- Calling `repaint` and `updateUI` from within the `paintComponent` method. You should avoid causing any new updates to the UI from occurring during a paint process.  This could cause your program to run wide and consume all the CPU cycles, not only making your app non-responsive, but also the whole system.

Some very quick points

- Swing is not thread safe.  You should never update the UI (or anything the UI relies on) from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  This example uses a Swing `Timer` as it allows the delay to occur of the EDT (and not block the UI), but it's updates are triggered within the EDT, allowing us to safely update the UI from within
- You create multiple instances of `Layout`, meaning that the one on the screen isn't the one which is been updated
- Your "freeze" logic is broken. It will never "freeze" anything

## Runnable example

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private AnimationPane animationPane;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            animationPane = new AnimationPane();

            JButton actionButton = new JButton("Start");
            actionButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    if (animationPane.isAnimating()) {
                        animationPane.stop();
                        actionButton.setText("Start");
                    } else {
                        animationPane.start();
                        actionButton.setText("Stop");
                    }
                }
            });

            add(animationPane);
            add(actionButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

    }

    // This is just makes it seem more random ;)
    private static Random RANDOM = new Random();

    public class Ball {

        private int x;
        private int y;

        private int xDelta;
        private int yDelta;

        private Color color;

        private Shape shape;

        public Ball(Color color) {
            shape = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 10, 10);
            this.color = color;

            // Get some random motion
            do {
                xDelta = RANDOM.nextInt(6) + 2;
                yDelta = RANDOM.nextInt(6) + 2;
            } while (xDelta == yDelta);
        }

        public void update(Rectangle bounds) {
            x += xDelta;
            y += yDelta;

            if (x + 10 > bounds.x + bounds.width) {
                x = bounds.x + bounds.width - 10;
                xDelta *= -1;
            } else if (x < bounds.x) {
                x = bounds.x;
                xDelta *= -1;
            }
            if (y + 10 > bounds.y + bounds.height) {
                y = bounds.y + bounds.height - 10;
                yDelta *= -1;
            } else if (y < bounds.y) {
                y = bounds.y;
                yDelta *= -1;
            }
        }

        public void paint(Graphics2D g2d) {
            // This makes it easier to restore the graphics context
            // back to it's original state
            Graphics2D copy = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();
            copy.setColor(color);
            copy.translate(x, y);
            copy.fill(shape);
            // Don't need the copy any more, get rid of it
            copy.dispose();
        }
    }

    public class AnimationPane extends JPanel {

        // This does not need to be static
        private List<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<>();  //Balls collection
        private Timer timer;

        private List<Color> colors;

        public AnimationPane() {
            colors = new ArrayList<>(8);
            colors.add(Color.RED);
            colors.add(Color.GREEN);
            colors.add(Color.BLUE);
            colors.add(Color.CYAN);
            colors.add(Color.MAGENTA);
            colors.add(Color.ORANGE);
            colors.add(Color.PINK);
            colors.add(Color.YELLOW);
            timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    if (RANDOM.nextBoolean()) {
                        makeBall();
                    }
                    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), getSize());
                    for (Ball ball : balls) {
                        ball.update(bounds);
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            makeBall();
        }

        protected void makeBall() {
            Collections.shuffle(colors);
            balls.add(new Ball(colors.get(0)));
        }

        public boolean isAnimating() {
            return timer.isRunning();
        }

        public void start() {
            timer.start();
        }

        public void stop() {
            timer.stop();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2.addRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON));
            // Bad ideas.  Repaint will cause a new paint event to be posted, causing your
            // UI to run away - consuming all your CPU cycles in a singulator forms
            // and destorys the known universe
            //repaint();
            // This doesn't do what you think it does and there shouldn't be
            // reason for you to call it
            //updateUI();

            // This is a bad idea as it could cause the paint cycles to slow down
            // destorying the responsiveness of your app
            // Besids, you should be passing this as the ImageObserver
//            try {
//                URL url = new URL("https://www.freejpg.com.ar/image-900/9c/9ca2/F100004898-textura_pasto_verde_linea_de_cal.jpg");
//                Image picture = ImageIO.read(url);
//                g.drawImage(picture, 0, 0, null);
//            } catch (IOException e) {
//                System.out.println("URL image was not found");
//            } finally {
//                try {
//                    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                    Image picture = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Home\\Desktop\\Cancha.jpg")); //Pitch
//                    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
//                    g.drawImage(picture, 0, 0, null);
//                } catch (IOException ex) {
//                    System.out.println("Pitch image was not found");
//                }
//            }
            // This is "bad" per say, but each ball should have it's own
            // concept of location
//            for (Image ball : balls) {  //I add balls to the Layout
//                g2.drawImage(ball, X, Y, 100, 100, null);
//            }
            for (Ball ball : balls) {
                ball.paint(g2);
            }
            // I made a copy of the graphics context, as this is shared
            // with all the other components been painted, changing the
            // render hints could cause issues
            g2.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering  Glad to see people that make well elaborated answers. Ps: Could you upvote my question?

Comment: Sorry for asking again, but I don´t completely dominate the Java language. Nevertheless, I had got another problem and it's that the button animate it doesn´t create a new ball; instead of taht, it returns the same ball to the start point and speed it up. Could you explain me please, why it's not creating a new one and why the ball's speed is incrementing? Updated code: code.sololearn.com/cEd16IG11o9J/#java

Ps: I loved your code :)